# Text widget doesn't appear in dialog after user Future.delayed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-dialog

I have a dialog that appears after user click on send button . When dialog appears , I want to show a text after 5 seconds . I use `Future.delayed` but the text doesn't appear at all . It appears only when I close the dialog and open it again . I want to show the text after 5 seconds from opening the dialog .

Here is my function

```
  void _initialize() {
    Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          visibility = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And here is my dialog code in the onTab of the button

```
_initialize()
 showDialog(context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,

        builder: (BuildContext contextd){

          return  WillPopScope(

            onWillPop: () {return Future.value(false);},
            child: Dialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.w, 20.h, 20.w, 20.h),
                child: Column(
                        children: [
                       //here are some widgets
                      Visibility(
                        visible:visibility?true:false,
                        child: Text("Resend?",style: TextStyle(decoration: 
                              TextDecoration.underline,),)),
               ],),
              ),
            ),
          );

        });
```

Comment: The dialog has its own context, not the same context of which you're trying to set the state.

Comment: I'm new at flutter so what is your advice ?

Comment: I'd suggest using a `StatefulBuilder`. I've posted an answer below with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `StatefulBuilder` like this:

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            return //somthing to return;
          },
        ));
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your `setState` that update `visibility` has a different context than builder dialog. `Visibility` is actually update but only appear in dialog when close and open again because this is how build dialog is updated. If you want to work with the context dialog need to use that widget:

```
StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
```

Into your dialog and then call that `setState`.

Comment: I dont know, flutter rebuild when call setstate or the screen changed (like open keyboard or change dimensions)

Comment: I use timer instead of Future.delayed but I cancel it after it finished . I don't know why it is repeating

Comment: Timer usually is used for loop calls. Better use future.delayed

Comment: I searched for how to stop future.delayed but all I found is to use timer instead

Comment: why you want to stop future.delayed? it only runs one time

Comment: I userd Future.delayed and also the print statment repeating

Comment: Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
               if (mounted) {
                 setState(() {
                   visibility = true;
                 });
               }
             });

              print("heelo");

Comment: how many times it repeats?

Comment: It is repeating after timer or Future.delayed is finished . I think sometimes 6 or 5 or 4 .. Here is from logs ->->

I/flutter ( 8785): heelo
I/flutter ( 8785): heelo
I/flutter ( 8785): success sent
I/flutter ( 8785): heelo
I/flutter ( 8785): heelo
I/flutter ( 8785): heelo

Comment: Think when you call setState all code inside of build is called again. So if you have whatever function inside of it, its called again. Check that.

Comment: As you see in the above comment it is repeating

Comment: Ok I will check that

Comment: I have to add setState to update the dialog

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [`StatefulBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html). Using the `bool visible` and the `setDialogState` argument, you can update the state of the contents of the dialog.

```js
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder(context, setDialogState) {
        // this variable is used for the conditional display
        bool visible = false;
        // this future will update the visible variable in 3 seconds, after the dialog is displayed already
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then(() => setDialogState(() { visible = true;}));
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () { return Future.value(false); },
          child: Dialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.w, 20.h, 20.w, 20.h),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  //here are some widgets
                  Visibility(
                    visible:visible,
                    child: Text(
                      "Resend?",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  ),
              ),
            ),
          );
      },
      );
};
```

Comment: Thanks but you miss : after builder of StatefulBuilder